# Very simple differential equation - where's my mistake?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve this very simple equation:

$(2y + e^y + x \cos(xy)) \frac{dy}{dx} + y \cos(xy) = 0$

I rewrite and continue as:

$(2y + e^y + x \cos(xy))dy + y \cos(xy)dx = 0$

$\int {y \cos(xy)dx} = -\int (2y + e^y + x \cos(xy))dy$

$\sin(xy) + c_1 = -y^2 - e^y - \sin(xy) + c_2$

$2 \sin(xy) + y^2 + e^y = c$

However, I am told the correct answer is:

$\sin(xy) + y^2 + e^y = c$

What gives?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  What happened to $2^y$, and did you mean $\sin(xy)$ where you wrote $\sin(x)$?

Comment: That's my mistake - it's 2y, not 2^y. And yes, I meant sin(xy)!

Comment: integrating $2y$ yields $y^\color{red}2$

Comment: Quick check: Wolfram Alpha agrees that it should be $y^2 + e^y + \sin(x y) = c_1$
Moreover, this seems to be an exact equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(2y + e^y + x \cos(xy))dy + y \cos(xy)dx = 0$$
Rearrange terms:
$$(2y + e^y )dy+  \cos(xy)(xdy+ydx) = 0$$
$$(2y + e^y )dy+  \cos(xy)dxy = 0$$
Integrate:
$$y^2 + e^y+  \sin(xy)= C$$

---

You can't integrate the way you did this
$$\int {y \cos(xy)dx} \neq -\int (2y + e^y + x \cos(xy))dy$$
Because $\cos (xy)$ is a function of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Indeed integration via separation of variables only works if you can actually separate the variables, well-spotted! This method uses the exact form of the equation if I am not mistaken.

$$P(x,y) dy + Q(x,y) dx=0 \text{ is exact }  \iff P_x =Q_y$$
Also check: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential_equation

Comment: Yes you're right. I used exact form to integrate easily @WesleyStrik

Comment: Of course, got it. Thanks.

Comment: Thats good. You're welcome @Katalina